# How to integrate Microsoft AX 2009(on-premise) to Microsoft Dataverse and dump to Azure datalake?

Tags: azure, dynamics-ax-2009, azure-data-lake-gen2, data-integration, dataverse

Can anyone give me any solution how to integrate it?

I have seen that we don't have any connector for ax 2009.

Any possible way we can connect to Microsot Ax 2009 as I have to migrate the data one time from there to dataverse then to datalake.

Answer (score 0):

AX 2009 is not supported as a connector.

You can connect to on-premises data over the [connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/connector-reference-powerapps-connectors) that use data gateway.

You can connect to on-premise databases using a [gateway connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/gateway-management):  It can work for most CRUD operations.

You can also create your own custom connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/register-custom-api

**Microsoft Dataverse to Azure Datalake -**

To copy data from Dataverse to Data Lake Storage Gen2 follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/export-to-data-lake-data-adf#set-the-data-lake-storage-gen2-storage-account-as-a-sink)

Reference - https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/power-apps-connecting-with-ax-2009/td-p/694811